# Lambdas stop invoking after a period of time

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Here's my setup:

A *Python 3.6 lambda function*, which I want to keep pre-warmed at a certain concurrency level (say, 10). The lambda's initialization is painful enough that I don't want to inflict this cost on visitors at random. I call these lambdas "workers"

A *Node lambda function* which runs every 5 minutes to try to pre-warm 10 instances. It uses the Event invocation type for 9 of them, and RequestResponse for 1. There's only either one or zero of this lambda running at any one time. I call this a "warmer".

I followed the guidelines at [https://www.jeremydaly.com/lambda-warmer-optimize-aws-lambda-function-cold-starts/], namely:

- Don’t ping more often than every 5 minutes
- Invoke the function directly (i.e. don’t use API Gateway to invoke it)
- Pass in a test payload that can be identified as such
- Create handler logic that replies accordingly without running the whole function

Here's a problem: this works great for several minutes. Then, as I watch the logs, I start to get timeouts from my worker lambda invocations. The timeouts quickly take over all the invocations that the warmer is trying to launch.

Now, no worker lambdas are prewarmed any more. But the warmer keeps on trying, on a Cloudwatch event cron schedule, suffering 100% timeouts. Finally, Lambda stops trying to launch my worker lambdas at all. It feels like some aspect of Lambda's getting its state scrambled. The only way to recover is to re-deploy the lambda. That buys me another hour with pre-warmed lambdas working.

Questions:

- How do I get visibility into why my worker lambdas start timing out, and then become completely non-responsive?
- What is the definition of a "Concurrent Execution"? On the main Lambda dashboard it shows me this chart of them. Yet, it seems to have more than twice as many Concurrent Executions as I'm requesting.

[image]
Here's the warmup lambda code (Node):

```
// warmer
"use strict";

/** Generated by Serverless WarmUP Plugin at ${new Date().toISOString()} */
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
aws.config.region = "${this.options.region}";
const lambda = new aws.Lambda({httpOptions: {timeout: 60000}});
const functionNames = ${JSON.stringify(functionNames)};
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
const concurrency = 10;
module.exports.warmUp = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log("Warm Up Start");
  const invokes = await Promise.all(functionNames.map(async (functionName) => {

    let invocations = [];

    try {
      for(let i=1;i <= concurrency;i++){
          let params = {
            FunctionName: functionName,
            InvocationType: (i===concurrency)?'RequestResponse': 'Event',
            LogType: 'None',
            Qualifier: process.env.SERVERLESS_ALIAS || "$LATEST",
            Payload: JSON.stringify({
              source: 'serverless-plugin-warmup',
              '__WARMER_INVOCATION__': i,
              '__WARMER_CONCURRENCY__': concurrency,
              '__WARMER_REQUESTED__': new Date().toISOString(),
            })
          };

          invocations.push(lambda.invoke(params).promise())
      }
      return await delay(75).then(Promise.all(invocations.map(p => p.catch(e => e)))
        .then(results => console.log('results', results))
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
          return e;
        }
        ))
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(\`Warm Up Invoke Error: \${functionName}\`, e);
      return false;
    }
  }));

  console.log(\`Warm Up Finished\`);

}
```

And here's the worker lambda (Python):

```
    source = event.get('source')
    if source == 'serverless-plugin-warmup':
        time.sleep(0.05)
        print(event)
        return lambda_gateway_response(200, {"status": "lambda warmup"})
```

Comment: *"I start to get timeouts from my worker lambda invocations"* ...this needs to be defined.  You get timeouts "from" them... observed where? What does this look like?

Comment: It looks like "  { TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 300000ms
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:83:34)", in the warmer's Cloudwatch logs. This keeps happening until I redeploy the function. Then it will work again, for about an hour.

Comment: So a timeout contacting the Lambda service API, then. 
 Initial impression: you are running the Lambda function inside a VPC, but the two subnets are not identical... one of the subnets associated with the Lambda function is not correctly configured to use a NAT Gateway as its default route.

Comment: Good guess, but we are not using a VPC :-) Also, the timeouts are totally absent for about an hour, then they start occurring. After that, it's kind of like Dutch Elm disease, I have to treat the worker lambda as dead and re-deploy.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks @Michael-sqlbot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the warmer (Node) lambda going haywire, even though all the logs pointed at the worker (Python) lambdas. After setting context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false, the problem disappeared.